# Update badge of icon and get the message of notification when the icon is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to update the badge of icon every time when a push  notification arrives and when i click the icon i want to get the message of notification.

For badge i tried to use a local notification in "applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotifications":

```
UILocalNotification * setBadge = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    setBadge.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Update the badge of app when a notif appears
    setBadge.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;

    setBadge.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];

    [app scheduleLocalNotification:setBadge];
```

and that

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;

None of them works.

To get the message of notification by clicking the icon is even harder

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this works fine in my project:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    self.isBackground = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AppChangeState object:@(self.isBackground)];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:DID_BECOME_ACTIVE
                                                                                         object:nil
                                                                                       userInfo:nil]];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you put somewhere an "addObserver"?